# Textchange event firing without any change in textbox contents

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a form with a record number, then boxes for "primary" notes and effective date.

Then I have an optional "secondary" notes and effective date box.

When someone clicks on a button to edit the primary or secondary notes, it looks to see if the other notes have changed (a session variable set to "true" fires for the "textchanged" event for the other textbox).  If so, instead of enabling the textbox that matched the "edit" button, it flashes a message saying to cancel or update the other textbox's changes.

My problem is that the contents of the textbox are being viewed as "changed" when nothing is changed.  If I load the record, and run a separate validation check, it verifies that the contents of the textbox match with the data originally loaded into the textbox.  Then, not changing anything, when I click on the "edit" button, that separate validation comes back as no longer matching, even though the information in the session variable and the textbox are both unchanged.

Here is my validation check -

```
        If Not Session("SN1") Is Nothing Then
        sesslst = sesslst & "<p>Sec Notes match = " & (Trim(Session.Item("SN1").ToString) = Trim(txtSecondaryNotes.Text)).ToString
        sesslst = sesslst & "<p>Sec Date match = " & (Trim(Session.Item("SD1").ToString) = Trim(txtSecEffDate.Text)).ToString
        sesslst = sesslst & "<p>S = " & Trim(Session.Item("SN1").ToString)
        sesslst = sesslst & "<p>F = " & Trim(txtSecondaryNotes.Text)
    End If
    lblTest.Text = sesslst
```

Here are the results after initial record load:

> SN1 - Bill Smith (Father) 10/12/1971 Linda Smith (Mother) 7/22/1971 Boudreau W Smith (Brother) 6/7/1994
>
> SD1 - 4/1/2014 12:00:00 AM
>
> Sec Notes match = True
>
> Sec Date match = True
>
> S = Bill Smith (Father) 10/12/1971 Linda Smith (Mother) 7/22/1971
>   Boudreau W Smith (Brother) 6/7/1994
>
> F = Bill Smith (Father) 10/12/1971 Linda Smith (Mother) 7/22/1971
>   Boudreau W Smith (Brother) 6/7/1994

(all specific data in this example has been changed, so no real personal information is being displayed)

When I click the edit button and that validation loop runs again, the "Sec Notes changed" value changes to "false," but nothing else changes.

Initially, I had the session variable for the record change set for the "TextChanged" event.  When it kept setting, despite no change, I added additional validation within the change event.  If both the notes and dates session variable do not match the field information, it sets another session variable as changed -

```
    Protected Sub txtSecondaryNotes_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSecondaryNotes.TextChanged, txtSecEffDate.TextChanged
    If Not ((Trim(Session.Item("SN1").ToString) = Trim(txtSecondaryNotes.Text)) And (Trim(Session.Item("SD1").ToString) = Trim(txtSecEffDate.Text))) Then
        Session.Item("secondaryEditing") = True
    End If

End Sub
```

I never get passed the check for the "secondaryEditing" session variable when I click the edit button (the lstSess() proc just lists all the session variable names and values so I can see what's being compared) -

```
    Protected Sub btnEditPrimary_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEditPrimary.Click
    txtPolicy.Text = Trim(txtPolicy.Text).ToUpper
    lstSess()

    If Session.Item("secondaryEditing") = True Then
        secMsg.Visible = True
        Exit Sub
    Else
        secMsg.Visible = False
    End If
```

So, I thought the problem, initially, was maybe with the form, loading of data, and the TextChanged event firing but not being evaluated until the button was pushed, but even when I add in the additional If-->then validation within the event, it still thinks something has changed, when the data in the field has not even been enabled, let alone manipulated.

How can I get this to honestly evaluate whether the text in the field has changed?  FYI - the asp:TextBox objects have been set with and without "AutoPostBack = 'true'" with no difference in how it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Save your efforts, folks.  The original programmer did not import all of the necessary System and System.Web classes.

Comment: This is the solution, but since it's my own and such a dumb and obvious thing, I don't want to take credit for it.  We can leave it here as a reminder, though.